# Source data settings for querying a SharePoint-File in Excels Power Query

Tags: excel, sharepoint, office365-apps

Hi supporters of Stack Overflow,

I am working at a small business and I'm attempting to create a worksheet that queries data from an Excel-file located on our local SharePoint. The worksheet that I’ve made is called filewithquery.xlsm and it’s sourcing from targetfile.xlsx.

I can easily make the query by pointing to the targetfile.xlsx location:
https://ourcompany.sharepoint.com/sites/common/shared%20documents/ourfolder/targetfile.xlsx
Here’s where it gets tricky.

If my colleague opens the file containing the query (filewithquery.xlsm) she can’t readily use the query. She will be prompted with a “Access Web content” box. Now regardless of what she choses she will not be able to query the target file.
However, by changing the query source data settings (in the Power Query Editor) to “Organizational account” (she will be prompted to log in) she can query the target file after logging in. I, however, then can’t readily query the target file. I will have to do the same procedure as her.

Any other source data setting (for instance “Anonymous”, “Windows”, etc.) doesn’t work. It will only work with “Organizational account”.

I am running Microsoft 365 Apps for business – Microsoft® Excel® for Microsoft 365 MSO (Version 2209 Build 16.0.15629.20200) 64-bit.

Is there anybody out there who can help me shed some light on what’s going on so that we both readily can use the query in our Excel-file (filewithquery.xlsm) without changing any settings?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to anonymous from Extri:Co. When making the quory it has to be made to the sharepoint folder. Not the file. Here's how the quory looks:

```
Let
   Source = SharePoint.Files("https://ourcompany.sharepoint.com/sites/common/", [ApiVersion = 15]),
   #"Targetfile xlsx_https://ourcompany.sharepoint.com/sites/common/shared%20documents/ourfolder/" = Source{[Name="Targetfile.xlsx",#"Folder Path"="https://ourcompany.sharepoint.com/sites/common/shared%20documents/ourfolder/"]}[Content],
   #"Imported Excel-project" = Excel.Workbook(#"Targetfile xlsx_https://ourcompany.sharepoint.com/sites/common/shared%20documents/ourfolder/")
in
   #"Imported Excel-project"
```

When people use the quory for the first time they will be asked to sign into their windows account. But they only have to do this one time.